# Function returns class of different type as defined causing segmentation fault

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault

I have declared a class so i can always get its parent node:

```
class EObject {
private: 
  EObject *mother;
public:
  EObject(EObject *mother=0);
  EObject *getMother() const {return mother;};
....
}
```

Now i have several classes which inherits this class like :

```
class EProperty : public QObject, public EObject {
Q_OBJECT
 ....
}
```

The root node is EModel which inherits `QAbstractItemModel` :

```
class EModel : public QAbstractItemModel,public EObject{
Q_OBJECT
...
    virtual QModelIndex parent(const QModelIndex &child) const {
        EObject *node =0;
        if ( child.isValid() ) {
            node = static_cast<EObject*>(child.internalPointer());
        } 

        if ( !node )
            return QModelIndex();

        EObject *parentNode = node->getMother();
        if ( !parentNode ) {
            // There are no parents
           return QModelIndex();
        }

        EObject *grandParentNode = parentNode->getMother();
        if ( !grandParentNode ) {
            // There are no parents
            return QModelIndex();
        }
        int row = grandParentNode->eChildren().indexOf(parentNode); 
        return createIndex(row,0,parentNode);
 }
```

Now i added some new classes:

```
class EParameter :public EProperty
{
    Q_OBJECT
    ....
 }
```

and

```
class EEnumeration :public EProperty
{
    Q_OBJECT
....

}
```

Now if i use `EParameter` everything is fine. But if i use `EEnumeration` i get a segmentation fault in this line `int row = grandParentNode->eChildren().indexOf(parentNode);` of the function `virtual QModelIndex parent(const QModelIndex &child) const`

The really strange part is that GDB says that `grandParentNode` which is declared as `EObject*` is of type `QObjectPrivate*` . I dont get how that can happen. 
I never touch the function `getMother()` anywhere. Also it would make no difference cause its not virtual.

Furthermore if i doublecheck the return value by writing :

```
EObject *grandParentNode = dynamic_cast(EObject*)(parentNode->getMother());
```

GDB still says `grandParentNode`  is of type `QObjectPrivate`

So the question is, how can a pointer be a different type than declared, even after a dynamic_cast?

I also tried to go step by step with GDB, and in the function `getMother()` everything seems fine `this` is fine and the value of `*mother` is also fine. When i get one step further so that i am back in the function `parent` the returned value is not the one which he showed me a second ago.

I tried this under windows 10 / qt 5.5.1 / mingw 492_32 and CentOS7.2 / qt 5.6.0 / g++ 4.8.4 , same behavior.

I totally don't understand it.

[image]

Comment: How do you print `grandParentNode` in GDB?

Comment: Sorry i dont get question. I use the debug mode of qt-creator and setting a break point  so i can look at the variable values. Is that what you were asking ?

Comment: No, not really :) . I am asking how are you printing `grandParentNode` within `GDB` when execution already stopped at breakpoint.

Comment: I added a screenshot ;)

Comment: You need to work this down to a [MCVE].

Comment: Your debugger shows to what type pointer (really) refers, not type of pointer itself. Look at other variables like `node` and `parentNode`.

Comment: Please post here `eChildren` function.

Comment: @PcAF yeah i know. The problem is not the line with `eChildren`. The question is how can `getMother()` return a pointer to a `QPrivateObject` which an  `EObject` doesnt know and also not inherited. `getMother` is only declared in class `EObject`. And why do i get the Object even if i do it with dynamic_cast, which should check it on runtime.

Comment: @davmac i will try to isolate the code, but its hard cause its one of the core componets. I wanted to give it a try maybe someone had something similar and could give me a hint

Comment: @J.W Look at constructor of `EObject`, it takes pointer to another `EObject`. Because you can pass pointer to derived as pointer to base, every pointer to class inheriting (directly or indirectly) from `EObject` can be passed as constructor argument. Somehow, Somewhere `QPrivateObject` must be inheriting from `EObject` (again directly or **indirectly**). However this isn't cause of SEGFAULT, in screenshot you posted I see that 2 member (`currentSender` and `extraData`) are initialized with `NULL`, maybe `eChildren()` somehow uses them.

Comment: I know thats the call of `eChildren()` causes the segfault. but its only a result of `grandParentNode` not being an EObject. So it tries to call `eChildren()` a function which is not part of class `QPrivateObject` and this is causing the segfault. If it would be inside the function `eChildren()` accessing an `nullpointer` the segfault would happen in the function itself. not in `parent()`